# python 3 parsing a semicolon separated very long string to remove each second element

Tags: python, string, parsing, separator

I'm pretty new to python and are looking for a way to get the following result from a long string
reading in lines of a textfile where each line looks like this

```
; 2:55:12;PuffDG;66,81; Puff4OG;66,75; Puff3OG;35,38;
```

after dataprocessing the data shall be stored in another textfile with this data

short example

```
2:55:12;66,81;66,75;35,38;
```

the real string is much longer but always with the same pattern

```
; 2:55:12;PuffDG;66,81; Puff4OG;66,75; Puff3OG;35,38; Puff2OG;30,25; Puff1OG;29,25; PuffFB;23,50; ....
```

So this means remove leading semicolon
keep second element

remove third element

keep fourth element

remove fith element

keep sixth element

and so on

the number of elements can vary so I guess as a first step I have to parse the string to get the number of elements and then do some looping through the string and assign each part that shall be kept to a variable

I have tried some variations of the command .split() but with no success.
Would it be easier to store all elements in a list and then for-loop through the list keeping and dropping elements?

If Yes how would this look like so at the end I have stored a file with
lines like this

```
2:55:12 ; 66,81 ; 66,75 ; 35,38 ;

2:56:12 ; 67,15 ; 74;16 ; 39,15 ;
```

etc. ....

best regards Stefan

Answer (score 1):

This solution works independently of the content between the semicolons

One line, though it's a bit messier:

```py
result = ' ; '.join(string.split(';')[1::2])
```

#### Getting rid of lead semicolon:

Just slice it off!

```py
string = string[2:]
```

#### Splitting by semicolon & every second element:

Given a string, we can split by semicolon:

```py
arr = string.split(';')[1::2]
```

The `[::2]` means to slice out every second element, starting with index 1. This keeps all "even" elements (second, fourth, etcetera).

#### Resulting string

To produce the string result you want, simply `.join`:

```py
result = ' ; '.join(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex based solution, which operates on the original input:

```py
inp = "; 2:55:12;PuffDG;66,81; Puff4OG;66,75; Puff3OG;35,38;"
output = re.sub(r'\s*[A-Z][^;]*?;', '', inp)[2:]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
2:55:12;66,81;66,75;35,38;
```

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to do it for one line of input if the same pattern repeats itself every time

```
input_str = "; 2:55:12;PuffDG;66,81; Puff4OG;66,75; Puff3OG;35,38;"

f = open('output.txt', 'w') # open text to write to
output_list = input_str.split(';')[1::2] # create list with numbers of interest 

# write to file
for out in output_list:
    f.write(f"{out.strip()} ; ")    
# end line
f.write("\n")
```

Answer (score -1):

thank you very much for the quick response. You are awesome.
Your solutions are very comact.

In the meantime I found another solution but this solution needs more lines of code

best regards Stefan

I'm not familiar with how to insert code as a code-section properly
So I add it as plain text

`fobj = open(r"C:\Users\Stefan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Heizung_2min.log")`
`wobj = open(r"C:\Users\Stefan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Heizung_number_2min.log","w")`

for line in fobj:
TextLine = fobj.readline()
print(TextLine)

```
myList = TextLine.split(';')

TextLine = ""
for index, item in enumerate(myList):

    if index % 2 == 1:  
      TextLine += item
      TextLine += ";"

TextLine += '\n'
print(TextLine)      
wobj.write(TextLine)
```

fobj.close()
wobj.close()`

Comment: even adding as plain text produces produces sliced code-section. Now StOF if your forum-software can't handle hyphens correctly not my bad